# Querying FQL without user

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-fql, checkin

I'm trying to get the number of recent checkins for multiple facebook places. I'd like to setup a CRON script that queries for recent checkins using something like:

```
SELECT tagged_uids FROM checkin WHERE timestamp > 1318514998 AND page_id IN (138444418096,138444418097)
```

But since this is a (fb userless) cron script, how can I get an access_token? I've tried getting one for a facebook app, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an [`offline_access`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) token and make sure that your script is on the same domain as your FB app that generated this token. **BUT** *I don't think* you can retrieve these info if you don't own the page.

Comment: Using the "Try this Query" link on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/ , I can edit the ?query variable in the URL and then get the user IDs of people who have checked in without me being friends with them. This is using the access token that facebook auto-generates when I click that link. Does that mean this info is public?